# Prediction interval as per probability

Tags: probability, predictive-models, nonlinear-regression, prediction-interval

I am practicing the regression problem using the sci-kit learn dataset. The dataset is about housing prices. When we use a regression model, it predicts a number. Based on the predicted value and actual value, we calculate MSE and RMSE to determine the productivity of the model. We can obtain prediction intervals as well. Most of the time we calculate the prediction interval at 95% to cover our errors. Similarly, I was wondering how can we predict prediction interval for other percentages. For example, instead of predicting single values, can we predict something like a 5% chance of the price falling in this range something like this. 25 % chance that the price will fall in this range and so on. And the price of the house cannot be negative so, in this situation how can we cover this edge case as well?

Is it possible to build? If it is possible, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you asking for a regression model which returns the probability distribution of housing prices?

Comment: Yes, @picky_porpoise. I want to predict housing price in probability. For example, 10% probability the housing price will fall in this range, 25% probability the housing price will fall in this range, 50 and so on. 
And if possible if we want to plot normal distribution then we can from there.

Comment: then I think you are not looking for a prediction interval. You can improve your question if you clarify that and also change the title.

Comment: @picky_porpoise but I want to predict prediction interval as per the probability. Most of the prediction interval are calculated at 95% which is probability, correct? So, in the same way, I want to calculate for other percentage.

Comment: Well the same algorithm which gives you 95% prediction intervals will also give you 25% prediction intervals if you change its parameters accordingly. I don't understand what you want to do.